# Выбрать и сложить ячейки с зависимостью одного столбца от другого

Tags: excel

Вот есть функция ВПР. Но минус в ней в том, что она вычисляет только одно - последнее значение, + необходимо постоянно сортировать таблицу по возрастанию. 
Может есть какая-то аналогичная функция?

Comment: А можно пример? Какие данные есть на вход и что нужно получить.

Comment: http://yadi.sk/d/gFzh3ot7QnimK

Необходимо получить сумму премий каждого цеха. (Не прибегая к VB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Задание студенческое, поэтому вряд ли решение подойдет для сдачи зачета :)

Но другим пользователям может быть полезна.

Формула массива (вводится одновременным нажатием *Ctrl+Shift+Enter*). Формула для *I16*:

```
=СУММ(СУММЕСЛИМН($L$5:$L$9;$D$5:$D$9;H16;$C$5:$C$9;$K$5:$K$9))
```

Суммируются данные диапазона *L5:L9* по условиям: работник (`K5:K9`) работает в цеху, указанному в *H16*

*СУММЕСЛИМН* формирует массив значений, которые суммируются функцией *СУММ*.

Формула из *I16* протягивается по строкам ниже.